# CodeIgniter: I'm able to list the items but I can't load one

Tags: php, codeigniter, slug, codeigniter-routing

My

Application/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Application/config/routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "news";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Application/models/news_model.php

```
<?php
class News_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
    {
        if ($slug === FALSE)
        {
            $query = $this->db->get('news');
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
?>
```

Applications/controlers/news.php

```
<?php
class News extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('news_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
        $data['title'] = 'News archive';

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }


    public function view($slug)
    {
        echo $slug;
        $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);
        var_dump($data);
        if (empty($data['news_item']))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
?>
```

Applications/views/index.php:

```
<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>
    <?php var_dump($news_item); ?>
    <h2><?php echo "<pre>"; echo $news_item['title'] ?></h2>
    <div id="main">
        <?php echo $news_item['text'] ?>
    </div>
    <p><a href="news/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">View article</a></p>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

And Applications/views/view.php

```
<?php
echo '<h2>'.$news_item['title'].'</h2>';
echo $news_item['text'];
```

The problem is that I can see index (wich lists my news) but when I click on a slug link it tries to go to:

```
/news/slug1
```

And it fires a not found error..

What am I missing here?

Comment: paste your news controller

Comment: I was editing. its in the question now! thx

Comment: the issue is simple, `slug1` becomes your action and because you don't have such an action, you get the error. Set your url like `news/view/slug1` and it will work

Comment: The requested URL /demo/news/view/noticia1 was not found on this server....   ( /demo/ is my project folder in localhost )

Comment: Your model's controller needs `parent::__construct()`.

Comment: it is already in the controller (as I posted it..)

Comment: Your `.htaccess` is at `Application/.htaccess`?  That's the wrong place.  It needs to be in your project folder (`/demo/` in your case).

Comment: I had the same issue.... I think it's a typo. I changed `<a href="news/` to `<a href="view/` and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Link should be:

```
 <p><a href="/news/view/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">View article</a></p>
```

Comment: The requested URL /demo/news/view/noticia2 was not found on this server.   ( /demo/ is the project folder )

Comment: No! it should be `<a href="<?php echo site_url('news/view/'.$news_item['slug'])?>">Link</a>`. That's if you want to do it right.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Your htaccess needs to stay in the demo folder, okay ?

Comment: @Twisted1919: When working with split structures in CI, it does not need to be so. But yeah site_url() is the default function to retrieve the site path, good point there.

Comment: @Raidenace - yes it does, it matters when your project is not in the webroot.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet: Is your document root pointing to the server folder installation of CI?

Comment: with '<?php echo site_url('news/view/'.$news_item['slug'])?>' the script crashes in the loop...

Comment: @Twisted1919: No it does not - because it that were the case, three CI installations I have been maintaining for over four years now would be broken all over the place. And site_url just gets what is set in your config, so it has no internal resolution mechanism anyways

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet - have you seen my comment about where htaccess should go ?

Comment: @Raidenace - maybe you are right after all, i don't work with CI for over two years now, so i might be mistaken.

Comment: @Twisted1919: no problemo, in fact I had forgotten about site_url for a while, thanks for the reminder.. Lets see if we can help the OP get his stuff up! Tony what does echo site_url() give you?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet - the htaccess looks okay, but it is not in the right place, move it in the demo folder, near index.php file

Comment: index.php is in /application/views/news/index.php shall i put it in news then?

Comment: .htaccess should be in your root folder. It is the folder where the index.php file resides along with folders such as system and application

Comment: Really? i just told you, put it in the demo folder, where your application folder is, on the same level as the main index.php file is. Makes sense ?

Comment: @Twisted1919: I got confused by what the OP said too... :|

Comment: Ah and also, your app crashed on site_url() usage because site_url() if i remember correctly is loaded via the url helper. so you will need to load the url helper in your controller, or autoload it, in order to use it in your views.

Comment: Ok toni, this looks like something is messed up. lets backtrack a bit. First, type in your whole url as link and first ensure that works. Like `http://localhost/whatever_is_here/news/views/id`. Next check site_url in any case to see how much of the complete working url above does it resolve to. Then check which are the missing pieces. These information will be needed to reach a proper solution

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet - i posted an updated htaccess, please try that one

Comment: I thought that it might be more productive if i uploaded the project... http://www53.zippyshare.com/v/12049811/file.html

Comment: Twisted1919 good point. Toni, you can add the helper into autoload config array if not already not there

Comment: Like this? $autoload['helper'] = array('url'); (it didnt help... :()

Comment: it works now!!!! I'm not really sure what was the problem because i think there might be a few...

Answer (score 0):

Controller's index method should be:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
    $data['title'] = 'News archive';

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('view', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

and article link must be:

```
<p><a href="news/index/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">View article</a></p>
```

Comment: You didn't change anything in the `index` method.  Also, this is what the `view` method is for.

Comment: of course I changed. Please look it more carefully:     $this->load->view('view', $data);

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your CI is in the /demo folder:
try this htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /demo/

#Needed for CodeIgniter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|pub|tmp|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Your action should be accessible at a url like:
`http://localhost:8080/demo/news/view/slug-here`
and `NOT` at:
`http://localhost:8080/demo/news/slug-here`

Comment: Have you updated your htaccess code? i don't see it updated in the archive you provided.

Comment: Yes I did... you posted this afterwards... :P